# Is it possible to change the formatting of a line based on what method is called?

Tags: eclipse

Formatting seems limited to 'change the color of X' (X being comments, operators, etc).

I'm trying to change the formatting of a line based on what the line contains, in this case, a call to w.d() (My logging subsystem).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything is possible in Eclipse because it's an open source platform designed to be extensible. However, you may need to write your own syntax highlighter plugin or use [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/2_0_0/195-highlighting.php). See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746031/how-can-i-create-a-custom-eclipse-syntax-highlighter) for more info.

Comment: It seems to be a real hassle so I'll pass, that said your answer is aboslutely correct, so thank you :D

Comment: @Shamrflow: It _is_ rather involved. I thought maybe there was a plugin out there already that makes custom highlighting easier to set up and came across [Eclipse Colorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html). If I'm reading the description right, it seems to allow you to create custom rules, such as by feeding it a pair of begin and end patterns. Perhaps you could give it a try.